# How to Run Appium Test in Real Android device or Emulator while building project in Jenkins server hosted in VM(Virtual Machine)

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, emulation, appium

I tried to Install and configure appium in Virtual Machine and successfully installed Appium. I face struggle in configuring the Real device or Emulator in local to the Appium in server. Is it possible to configure the Real device or Emulator to the appium server while building through Jenkins for testing? Or Is there any plugins available for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to run automation Appium Test while building project in Remote Jenkins Server.

Initially, I installed Android Emulator plugin and run Android Emulator by configuring build step in Jenkins. It starts the emulator during Jenkins' build and the Android Emulator run peacefully in the background. But the problem is when I run the appium server through Shell script, it doesn't detect the Jenkins' emulator.

So, I tried with starting default emulator through Shell Script and Appium Server in parallel. Now, the Appium detects the Emulator and I can run the test cases successfully.

I used the Shell Script as follows to run the test in Jenkins' build step.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Kill adb:
killall adb &
wait

echo Start adb:
adb start-server &
wait

echo Kill Node:
killall node &
wait

echo Start Appium:
emulator -avd Test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window &
appium &
sleep 2m
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android emulator plugin in Jenkins.
See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

You can try to:

1.install Android SDK and download emulator images
2.install emulator plugin in jenkins management
3.Add start emulator step in your jenkins job

But the plugin is not that good to use, sometimes the boot-up of emulator is timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried with the plugin. My Issue is that executing the test in real device from Jenkins server build is possible or not?

Comment: should be also ok, you can connect the device to jenkins, and run unit test in in a jenkins job. But you have to make sure the device is not screen-locked. Or you can add some command in the job to unlock the screen.

Comment: I have remote virtual server for Jenkins  and I want to know is it possible to connect to devices at the host.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that you can use jenkins emulator plugin.
Just in case you see the issue that appium can't see connected android emulator, you might want to change the adbport